# Laravel Seperate folders for Web and API Controllers causing error

Tags: laravel

Im currently trying to create an API for my laravel project,

I have decided to move my API controllers into a subfolder of Controllers. This is the folder structure:
[image: Folder Structure]

This is the routes file for the api:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use app\Http\Controllers\APIControllers;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function() {

    Route::get('/event_locations', 'EventLocationsAPIController@all');
});
```

And this is the EventLocationsAPIController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\APIControllers;

use App\EventLocation;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class EventLocationAPIController extends Controller
{

    public function all()
    {
        $locations = EventLocation::all();

        return response()->json($locations);
    }

}
```

When I send an GET request to `/api/v1/event_locations` I get the following error

`Target class [App\Http\Controllers\EventLocationsAPIController] does not exist.`

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the namespace in route group as well.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1','namespace'=>'APIControllers'], function() {

    Route::get('/event_locations', 'EventLocationAPIController@all');
});
```

you have given **`EventLocations`** plural and the controller name is singular **`EventLocation`** change the name of the controller as **EventLocationAPIController**  in the route file.

Comment: I tried this and unfortunately still am getting the same error.

Comment: your `EventLocationAPIController` name is wrong change it as the same mine.

Comment: Ah I see the problem now! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your nameaspace on router's group like this:

```php
Route::namespace('APIControllers')->group(function () {
    // Controllers Within The "App\Http\Controllers\APIControllers" Namespace
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function() {
        Route::get('/event_locations', 'EventLocationAPIController@all');
    });
});
```

Check [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-group-namespaces) for more info.

Comment: I tried this and unfortunately still am getting the same error.